# How to format Django views' docstring

Tags: django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

I use simple views in my project, and now my project begin to be bigger, I'm writing a sphinx doc and use objects docstrings with `sphinx.ext.autodoc` for inclusion.

My trouble is: How to greatly format view's docstring ?

- Document GET/POST and more behavior.
- Template(s) used
- Context content

For example, I'm using:

```
def my_view(request):
    """
    Do something depending of HTTP method.

    In GET: Returns a page
    IN POST: Make something and redirect

    GET parameters:
    GET['next'] : URL to redirect to after submit form

    POST parameters:
    POST['action'] : Action
    """
```

I'm self-asking if there is a better way to do this ?
Is there any consensus about it ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/

Comment: @Albert You should post it as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few examples you can find here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/